# How to delete quotation marks from text array?

Tags: php

My code simply displays a random line from a text file,
But in my text file most of the proxies look like this: "11.15.19.15:80" I need help how to display only the address on the site, and remove the quotation marks.

```
<?php
$message_array = file("proxies.txt");
$message = array_rand($message_array);
echo "$message_array[$message]";
?>
```

Comment: Look in to a "preg_replace()" function.

Comment: ^ overkill just use `str_replace` or even `trim()` in this case

Comment: ^good point. Yes, use str_replace instead.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wrap the string in a **[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)**:

```
<?php
$message_array = file("proxies.txt");
$message = array_rand($message_array);
echo trim($message_array[$message], "\""); // 11.15.19.15:80
?>
```

Note that the second argument in `trim()` is needed, because your string **contains** the `"` characters, rather than uses them to denote the string itself. Adding an escaped backslash (`"\""`) removes the quotation marks from what is inside the string itself.

I've created a simple demonstration of this at [**3v4l.org here**](https://3v4l.org/KenqS).

Comment: lol think about that, you had me confused for a second but a character mask still required

Comment: The quote around it suggests its a string, it's not part of the actual string though. So if the line is `"11.15.19.15:80"`, the quotes won't be removed. You could specify a second argument to `trim()`, https://3v4l.org/KenqS.

Comment: i think the title is a bit of a give-away dont you?

Comment: @Qirel -- Ahh, that's actually a very good point! I've updated my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like so:

```
preg_replace('/["]*/g', '', $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace`. Here is an example:

```
$message = str_replace('"', '',$message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function if you just need to remove the double quotes:

```
$message = trim($message, '"');
```

Also [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$message = str_replace('"', '', $message);
```